# changing HTML tag properties using inline server tags

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I have the following submit button:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" runat="server"/>
</form>
```

How do I change e.g. the background colour of the button itself by using inline server tags after the button has been clicked?

I've tried using the attribute style="" in the submit buttons declaration with inline server tags <%%>, but I just get a Parser error message saying "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs."

Expected code to be used to verify button click:

```
<%
  if (Request["submit"] != null) 
  {
   // CODE HERE  
  }
%>
```

Comment: why can't you use jQuery for changing back color or so, which has no significance at server side?

Comment: My question has server-side significance, not client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <%
      if (Request["submit"] != null) 
      { %>
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" runat="server" style="background:#ffffff"/>
     <% }
       else{ %>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" runat="server" style="background:#aaaaaa"/>
    <%}%>
</form>
```

or

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <% string color="";
          if (Request["submit"] != null) 
          { %>
     color="background:#aaaaaa";
         <% }%>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="<%=color%>"/>
    </form>
```

If you use the second one you the submit button can not have runat="server" attribute

Comment: Thank you!
But is there any way to prevent the reuse of the html submit code?

Comment: i didn't quiet get your question, if the button exists user would be able to click on it again. do you mean that user wouldn't be able to click on it and resend the data?

Comment: I would just like to change the background colour of the submit button after it's been clicked - Nothing else :-)

Comment: Yes, the background colour of the submit button.

Comment: well the code **if (Request["submit"] != null)** will be valid after the submission. in the code above that I have written only there will be one submit button. if submitted by this button the button will have the color that is in the if clause and otherwise it will have the color of else clause

Comment: Yes I know that, but I am talking about the reuse of the HTML code, not the result output :-)
Any way to avoid the reuse of HTML code like in your example?

Comment: let me put it this way, you can not change color with a server side code, unless when rendering there is a third way (that I don't recomand) and that is you insert a javascript code in your if command that changes the button color

Comment: It should be possible with raw HTML code, since it's possible with ASP.NET Webform controls.
E.g. <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /> -- Page_Load eventhandler: { Button1.BackColor = Color.Aqua; }

Comment: well its (page_load) before the page is pre-rendered, but the code you have written occurs after it

Answer (score 0):

its not proper way to mix the server side code with the HTML markups..
use code behind for such things..

try the following..

```
if(Request["submit"]==null)
        submit.Style.Add("background", "red");
else
        submit.Style.Add("background", "white");
```